# Get the length of property of first array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays

```
array1 = [
    {name: "samsung", views: 1200},
    {name: "apple", views: 200}
]

array2 = [
    {name: "samsung-1234", views: 200},
    {name: "apple-2332", views: 200},
    {name: "samsung-6543", views: 400},
    {name: "samsung-9876", views: 600}
]
```

How can I get `sumsung` has 3 types and `apple` has `1` type in array2.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Loop and count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `array2` and specify `name` from `array1` to build the filter and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to compare names

```js
let array1 = [
    {name: "samsung", views: 1200},
    {name: "apple", views: 200}
];

let array2 = [
    {name: "samsung-1234", views: 200},
    {name: "apple-2332", views: 200},
    {name: "samsung-6543", views: 400},
    {name: "samsung-9876", views: 600}
];


let result = array1.map(x => ({ name: x.name, total: array2.filter(a => a.name.includes(x.name)).length }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a map for counting the occurence and update `array1`.

```js
var array1 = [{ name: "samsung", views: 1200 }, { name: "apple", views: 200 }],
    array2 = [{ name: "samsung-1234", views: 200 }, { name: "apple-2332", views: 200 }, { name: "samsung-6543", views: 400 }, { name: "samsung-9876", views: 600 }];
    types = new Map(array1.map(o => ([o.name, Object.assign(o, { types: 0 })])));
    
array2.forEach(({ name }) => ++types.get(name.split('-')[0]).types);

console.log(array1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1.map(el => {
    return array2.filter(el2 => {
        return el2.name.includes(el.name)
    })
})
```

Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the significance of the first array, but you can get the number of items with Samsung with a simple for loop.

```
let cnt = 0;
array2.forEach((val) => {if (val.name.match(/samsung/i)) { cnt++}})
console.log(cnt) // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
array1 = [
    {name: "samsung", views: 1200},
    {name: "apple", views: 200}
]

array2 = [
    {name: "samsung-1234", views: 200},
    {name: "apple-2332", views: 200},
    {name: "samsung-6543", views: 400},
    {name: "samsung-9876", views: 600}
]

const result = array1.map(brand => {
    let howManyTypes = array2.filter(ele =>  ele.name.indexOf(brand.name) != -1).length;
    return {name: brand.name, howManyTypes}
})

console.log(result)
```